# My jquery works but I wish clicked list item execute first and then previous action excute

Tags: jquery

```js
$('.nav ul li').click(function(){
    $('.nav ul li').animate({right:0});
    $(this).css({'position':'relative'}).animate({right:100});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link-3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link-4</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I expect targated list item (right:100) execute first and then previous or next list item action (right : 0) execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not(this) function can be added to select others as follows:

```js
 $('.nav ul li').click(function(){
  $(this).css({'position':'relative'}).animate({right:100},function(){
    $('.nav ul li').not(this).animate({right:0});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
    <ul>
    <li style="background:black"><a href="#">link-1</a></li>
    <li style="background:black"><a href="#">link-2</a></li>
    <li style="background:black"><a href="#">link-3</a></li>
    <li style="background:black"><a href="#">link-4</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I am glad, that it works exact as per your requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.nav ul li').click(function(){
    var target = $(this);
    $(".nav ul li").animate({right:0},100,function(){
       $(target).css({'position':'relative'}).animate({right:100});  
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link-3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link-4</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```